# R: Can't get get() to recognize extraction of data frames

Tags: r

I am struggling with the `get()` function and extracting from data `frames` or `arrays`.

Consider:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:4, b=2:5)
> length(df)
[1] 2
> length(get("df"))
[1] 2
> length(df$a)
[1] 4
> length(get("df$a"))
Error in get("df$a") : object 'df$a' not found
> length(df[, 1])
[1] 4
> length(get("df[, 1]"))
Error in get("df[, 1]") : object 'df[, 1]' not found
```

Is there a way to get `get()` to play well with extraction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably need to parse the expression to do it all within get but why not this:

```
length(get("df")$a)
[1] 4
```

And you could also extract with a named character if you use "[[":

```
> mychar <- "a"
> length(get("df")[[mychar]])
[1] 4
```

Comment: Great, I do not need the entire expression within get() ... using just the variable prior to extraction works, as you show. Your second example solved my problem of programmatically defining the column name to extract.